# Am I structuring my project/scripts in a pythonic way - feedback

Tags: python, class, oop, module

New to big projects. I'd like some pointers on how I've structured my code. For simplicity I've replaced all function code blocks with 'pass' statements and removed imports etc.

My code gets network info from an API, which I eventually will filter to store the relevant response data into a MySQL database. The RoadmLine objs have lots of attributes (id, length, loss, type) etc hence why I want to approach this with Classes.

Structure / Code below :)

### Folder struct

```
C:.
│   .gitignore
│   main.py
│
├───db
│       database.py
│
├───mcp
│       roadmline.py
│       session.py
│
└───tests
```

#### main.py

```
# Initialize instance of Session, Check MCP server readiness abort if server response not okay
session = Session()
assert session.ping() == 200

# Initialize instance of Database, Connect to MySQL database
db = Database()
db.connect()   

# Initialize a single instance of RoadmLine, to get number of RoadmLine ids returned by MCP
roadm = RoadmLine()
num_roadms = roadm.get_num_roadms()

# Create x number of RoadmLine instances based on the value of class variable num_roadms
roadms = [RoadmLine() for x in range(num_roadms)]
print(f"Created {num_roadms} instances of RoadmLines.")
```

#### database.py

```
class Database:
    """A class to manage the connection with #######."""
    
    # Class constants
    HOST = ####
    DB = ####
    USER = ####
    PASS = ####

    def __init__(self):
        self.connection = None

    def connect(self):
        """Connect to MySQL database."""
        pass

    def disconnect(self):
        """Disconnect from MySQL database."""
        pass

    def query(self):
        """Query table entries in MySQL."""
        pass

    def update(self):
        """Update table entries in MySQL."""
        pass
```

#### session.py

```
class Session:
    """A class to manage MCP sessions."""

    # Class Constants
    HOST = "https://#####"
    UNAME = "####"
    PWORD = "####"

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializes a session"""
        pass

    def ping(self):
        """Pings the MCP server for response."""
        pass

    def get_token(self):
        """Retrieves a bearer auth token from MCP"""
        pass
```

#### roadmline.py

```
class RoadmLine:
    """A class to represent a roadmline"""

    # Class variables
    num_roadms = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.session = Session()
        self.session.get_token()

    def get_num_roadms(self):
        """API call to MCP to retrieve total number roadmlines"""
        pass

    def get_roadm_ids(self):
        """API call to MCP to get all roadmlines"""
        pass
```

Comment: I'd probably also add `requirements.txt`. Just do `pip freeze > requirements.txt`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for [codereview.se].

Comment: @ekhumoro where can I find the post rules?

Comment: For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I am not sure, but maybe there is no plain rule about this case. But indirectly, there is not a specific problem with the code you want help with debugging. What you are asking is better answered there, and moving the post there is a good suggestion.

Comment: I think voting to close may look a bit harsh (but surely not meant to be so), but it is only one way to sign what probably should be done.

Comment: @opticMan CodeReview is for when "[you have a working piece of code from your project and are looking for open-ended feedback in the following areas: Application of best practices and design pattern usage](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)", etc. StackOverflow is intended for much more specific programming problems.

Comment: Okay thanks I’ll check out codereview but leaving the question opened for others who are in my pos that view it